# надо развернуть столбец в строку Pivot

Tags: oracle11g

Всем доброго времени суток.
У меня есть таблица table1 а в результат должно выглядеть так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже решил тогда просто срочно  нужно была решать а этом  сайте не знал что тут есть люди как вы !!

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.